# LSTM input produces nans in non-text classification problem

Tags: python, input, data-structures, lstm, keras-layer

LSTM model on non-text data is trained to classify two -classes.
I have 225 time points for each product (N=730), with 167 features including the target. Only the last time point is to be predicted. 
I use the target as a feature in predictions: here is how I prepare the input:

```
def split_sequences(sequences, n_steps, n_steps_out):
    X, y = list(), list()
    for i in range(n_steps_out):
        # gather input and output parts of the pattern
        y.append(sequences[n_steps + i:n_steps + i + 1, -1][0])
        #targ = sequences[n_steps + i:n_steps + i + 1, -1][0]
        #y.append(int(targ)) if ((targ==0) | (targ==1)) else y.append(2)
    X.append(sequences[:n_steps, :])
    return np.asarray(X).reshape(n_steps, sequences.shape[1]), np.asarray(y).reshape(n_steps_out)

#del X_train_minmax, X_test_minmax
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))

#X_train_minmax = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X_train.iloc[:, 0:166])
#X_test_minmax  = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X_test.iloc[:, 0:166])
X_train_minmax = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X_train) ##all features included
X_test_minmax  = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X_test)

print(X_train_minmax.shape)
print(X_test_minmax.shape) 

seq_samples = 631
seq_samples2 = 99
time_steps = 225
periods_to_predict = 1
periods_to_train = time_steps - periods_to_predict ##here may be a problem
# 
features = 167
X_train_reshaped = X_train_minmax.reshape(seq_samples,time_steps,features)
X_test_reshaped  = X_test_minmax.reshape(seq_samples2, time_steps,features)

data_train = [split_sequences(x, periods_to_train , periods_to_predict) for x in X_train_reshaped] ##and here i shoud check the function
data_test = [split_sequences(x, periods_to_train , periods_to_predict) for x in X_test_reshaped]
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = [], [], [], []

for x in data_train:
    X_train.append(x[0])
    y_train.append(x[1])
for x in data_test:
    X_test.append(x[0])
    y_test.append(x[1])

X_train = np.asarray(X_train)
y_train = np.asarray(y_train)
X_test = np.asarray(X_test)
y_test = np.asarray(y_test)
```

I experimented with the following shapes for the input data

```
print(X_train.shape) #(631, 224, 167)
print(X_test.shape) #(99, 224, 167)
print(y_train.shape) #(631, 1) 
print(np.unique(y_train)) #[0. 1.]
y_train_cat=to_categorical(y_train) 
print(y_train_cat.shape)  #(631, 2)
```

### Both categorical and binary models produce nans in prediction, and the training is clearly wrong. It must be something obvious that i'm missing (I suspected problems in the training periods =224, i.e. 225-1 or units=2 in the last layer). I tried different shapes and combinations , but failed and will greatly appreciate any clue.

```
model=Sequential([
            LSTM(units=100,  
            input_shape=(periods_to_train,features), kernel_initializer='he_uniform',
            activation ='linear', kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3.), return_sequences=False),
            Dropout(rate=0.5),
            Dense(units=100,                   kernel_initializer='he_uniform', 
            activation='linear', kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)),
            Dropout(rate=0.5),
            Dense(units=100,                  kernel_initializer='he_uniform',
            activation='linear', kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)),
            Dropout(rate=0.5),
            Dense(units=1, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', activation='sigmoid')])

       # Compile model
optimizer = Adamax(lr=0.001, decay=0.1)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

configure(gpu_ind=True)
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_split=0.1, batch_size=100, epochs=8, shuffle=True)

_________________________________________________________________
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 100)               107200    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 100)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 100)               10100     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 100)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 100)               10100     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 100)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 101       
=================================================================
Total params: 127,501
Trainable params: 127,501
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

This is my predicted array, 
`y_hat_val = model.predict(X_test)`

```
       [nan],
       [nan],
       [nan],
       [nan],
       [nan],
       [nan],
       [nan],
       [nan],
       [nan],
       [nan],
       [nan],
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

After running simulations, I found that maximal possible time_steps (m) that does not result in nans for the matrix of this shape - is m=163.

After that correction the model produces meaningful predictions.
Another issue to look at is the preparation of input train set. 
If `return_sequences` argument is used, train set
should include the actual N of time_steps and not N-1, as in the example. 
Below is how the train set can be transformed

```
X_train_minmax = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X_train) ##all features included
X_train_reshaped = X_train_minmax.reshape(seq_samples,time_steps,features)
```

Comment: Just a heads up fyi, there is a Data Science Stack ( https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ ) which may be helpful to you or for related questions in the future!